# How can I count the number of bytes in a binary file in Bash?

Tags: bash

In Bash, I can count the number of bytes in a text file like this:

```
cat textfile.txt | wc -c
```

However, I can’t `cat` the contents of a binary file, e.g., a PNG bitmap image file, to standard input.

How can I count the number of bytes in a bitmap image file?

I’d rather not count the number of bytes used to store it on disk, as I understand that this can differ between operating systems. Instead, I’m looking for a way to count the number of bytes that would be transferred if the file were served over HTTP (discounting HTTP headers, of course).

Comment: You should be fine just using the file size. The whole "size on disk" thing is secondary and I doubt *nix of all things would give you that number as the file's size.

Comment: "can't `cat` the contents of a bitmap image file (e.g. a PNG) to standard input." - *Sure you can.* But as Jim Lewis points out, it's unnecessary to use `cat` since `wc` accepts a filename (or you can use redirection).

Comment: @jnpcl: yeah, now that I’m looking, that does seem to be the case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`wc -c yourimg.png` should do what you want, without a “[useless use of `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html)”.

Comment: Hmmm: that does make sense, but I’m getting `wc -c` reporting e.g. 1814 bytes for a file that the Mac OS X Finder says is 27,008 bytes.

Comment: That said, `ls` and `stat` are reporting the same size. Huh.

Comment: To get the size without the filename in the output: `wc -c < filename`

Comment: I think maybe my PNGs were a bit weird, due to being saved by PhotoShop. I’ve just saved them with Acorn, which uses pngcrush to reduce their size as much as possible, and now the Finder, `ls`, `stat` and `wc` all report the same sizes.

Comment: @Paul: the OS X Finder should show you both. For example, I have an HTML snippet on my desktop that's 397 bytes, yet the Finder says it's 4KB. That just means that the hard drive was formatted using 4KB blocks, and even though the file size is much smaller, it still has to use 1 block to store it.

Comment: @jnpcl: Ah, right — I thought the bytes count in the Finder get info window was the size on disk, as opposed to the “actual” size. I see now it’s giving me the actual size. I think this all shows just how little I understand about file sizes in general.

Comment: @jim-lewis: I deleted my answer claiming that `wc -c` would not work correctly on binary files. It was a stupid user error making me jump into the conclusion and the first comment seemed to confirm my observation. Now testing 1000s of binary files all of them were reported correctly. Thanks for following up! (SO does not allow me to correct my downvote on your answer into an upvote before you edit it.)